# ROS Answers SE migration: apriltag_ros

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone
I want to know how to use apriltag on absolute coordinates
I see the website https://blog.csdn.net/TFZ941214/article/details/90711885?utm_medium=distribute.pc_relevant.none-task-blog-BlogCommendFromMachineLearnPai2-3.nonecase&depth_1-utm_source=distribute.pc_relevant.none-task-blog-BlogCommendFromMachineLearnPai2-3.nonecase
here is seems to relative coordinates can anyone help?
And I want to know in the website the tag_yaml the means about x y z?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/355498/apriltag_ros/) by [Xiao](https://answers.ros.org/users/49973/xiao/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2020-06-21

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lennart](https://answers.ros.org/users/52806/lennart/) on 2020-06-29**:
Is this Question solved? I've yes please mark the Question as solved or tell us how you solved the Question.
If the Question is not solved yet than tell us what you don't understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The apriltag_ros gives you the relative coordinates from the camera to the apriltag. They are also given as tf-frame see tf-package. If you connect your camera-frame with your fixed frame (normaly world or map). You've got your absolut coordinates.
The Z-axis is in the direction of the camera view. X and Y are the other both axis (up and the the right side).
Hope I could help you.

---

Originally posted by [Lennart](https://answers.ros.org/users/52806/lennart/) with karma: 40 on 2020-06-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1